# Creating hyperlinks in Xtext

Tags: xtext

In my grammar I use `importURI=STRING`.

Now, I need create a hyperlink for STRING.

I create `MyDslHyperlinkHelper` in package `mydsl.ui.navigation`.
And I add in file MyDslUiModule this method:

```
@Override
public Class<? extends IHyperlinkHelper> bindIHyperlinkHelper() {
    return MyDslHyperlinkHelper.class;
}
```

But the method `void createHyperlinksByOffset(XtextResource resource, int offset,                      IHyperlinkAcceptor acceptor)` of the class `MyDslHyperlinkHelper` is never executed.

Can you explain me why?

**EDIT:**

I have this code:

```
@Override
        public void createHyperlinksByOffset(XtextResource resource, int offset,
                        IHyperlinkAcceptor acceptor) {

            INode node = NodeModelUtils.findLeafNodeAtOffset(resource.getParseResult().getRootNode(), offset);
            if (node != null && node.getGrammarElement() instanceof RuleCall && node.getSemanticElement() instanceof Import) {
                if (ga.getSTRINGRule().equals(((RuleCall)node.getGrammarElement()).getRule())) {
                    Import i = (Import) node.getSemanticElement();
                    String uriString = i.getImportURI();
                    URI uri = URI.createURI(uriString);
                    final URIConverter uriConverter = resource.getResourceSet().getURIConverter();
                    final URI normalized = uri.isPlatformResource() ? uri : uriConverter.normalize(uri);
                    final URI targetURI = gsp.getResourceDescriptions(resource, Lists.newArrayList(normalized)).getResourceDescription(normalized).getURI();
                    XtextHyperlink result = hyperlinkProvider.get();
                    result.setURI(targetURI);
                    Region region = new Region(node.getOffset(), node.getLength());
                    result.setHyperlinkRegion(region);
                    result.setHyperlinkText(uriString);
                    result.open();
                    acceptor.accept(result);
                }
            }
            super.createHyperlinksByOffset(resource, offset, acceptor);
        }
```

But the file didn't open. Why this happens?

Comment: i cannot reproduce that. how does the impl look like?

Comment: At the moment, I use only a print in method `createHyperlinksByOffset`. But when I create this `bindIHyperlinkHelper` with return `MyDslHyperlinkHelper.class;` should work? Or I need more configurations?

Comment: No that should work that Way and did when i tried it. Did you try to debug it

Comment: Yes, and I have an error when load some classes. This is the error "the jar file C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar has no source attachment". How can I resolve this error?